# jquery autocomplete - mouse below text box a causes selection after menu is shown

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, mouseover, enter

I have a jquery autocomplete text box at the top of a page. Typically, a user will click in the text box to give it focus, move the mouse away, and then start typing. If the user moves the mouse below the autocomplete, their mouse location can inadvertently select a suggestion, even though they didn't do anything. When this happens and the user hits the enter key, the autocomplete uses their inadvertent selection.

This is a major problem due to the location of my autocomplete... it happens all the time, and is extremely frustrating to my users. I need a solution, but I can't seem to get the autocomplete to give me the keypress event first.

Here's my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uqTv9/2/

Comment: Wouldn't keeping the enter key's functionality as-is and removing the autocomplete's default selection be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can use select event to prevent enter like this :

```
$('#query').autocomplete({
    source: [
        "A",
        "AAA",
        "AAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
    ],
    select: function(e, ui) {
        if(e.which === 13 ) {  return false; }
    }
});
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/xSKPz/1/

Comment: Perfect! For some reason I was thinking I needed to look at the keypress event.

Answer (score 0):

The below is a hack and basically it negates the jQuery styling and selection. Implemented the search callback and added hack in there to remove jQuery styling and removed the hack when the mouse is moved.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/uqTv9/13/)

**Note:** I haven't got a chance to try for the enter key yet.

```
$('#query').autocomplete({
    source: [
        "A",
        "AAA",
        "AAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA",
        "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        ],
    search: function(event, ui) {
        $(document).on('mouseenter', '.ui-menu-item a', function(e) {
            //Remove jQuery styling and selection.
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
            this.id = '';
            e.preventDefault();
        }).one('mousemove', '.ui-menu-item a', function(e) {
            //implement mouse move once if moved inside the same li>a
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
            this.id = 'ui-active-menuitem';

           //unbind the mouse event so it works as normal
           $(document).on('mouseenter', '.ui-autocomplete', function(e) {
               $(document).off('mouseenter', '.ui-menu-item a');
            });
        });
    }
});
$('#query').keypress(function(ev) {
    if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
        alert('query: ' + $(this).val());
        return (false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This thread is already closed but since I had a similar problem and the solution listed above didn't worked for me, I would like to share this solution.

It consists of focusing the first element after the results list is opened.

```
$('.selector').autocomplete({
    open: function () {
        var w = $(this).autocomplete('widget');
        setTimeout(function () { $('li:first', w).mouseover(); }, 50);
    }
});
```

My problem was when you leave the mouse pointer under the textbox then start typing the search the autocomplete selects the item under the mouse pointer and not the first.

Comment: Interesting approach... so you're basically allowing the mouse position to select the item under it, and then forcing a mouseover event on the first item after 50ms. What if the user doesn't want that item either? With some UXs, the user enters text and hits enter, ignoring all selections. Seems like your solution prevents this use case from working. Is that correct?